# dataset access for icpsr members

Tags: data-request

I've just found a dataset which would really fit my intentions with an assignment I was given. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to access the data neither is the college where I study. I wonder  if someone would be able to access it and download it for me.  http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/RCMD/studies/35163#usage

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid that Open Data SE is not the right place for this kind of request …

Answer (score 2):

Login to the website using Google+ or Facebook. Then select the type of organization and field. I have a media organization, so I selected News Organization and Humanities.

It then took me to a page of Terms & Agreements (which I read!) and agreed. From that point on, I was able to download datasets.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the documentation not the actual data. "These data are available only to users at ICPSR member institutions "

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini - In opened the zip file that I downloaded. Your right, it has the questionnaires in PDF format, but not the data.